# What is the difference between E F and E ~ F css3 selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

After reading [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) on CSS3 selectors, I am still a little bit confused, what is the difference between E F and E ~ F selectors.

```
E   F   an F element descendant of an E element
E ~ F   an F element preceded by an E element
```

In my opinion they are absolutely the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
E F
```

selects an Element `F` which is a child (descendant) of `E`. So you have a nested structure, where `E` is the *parent* (ancestor) of `F`.

```
<!-- E F will match: -->
<e>
  <f></f>
</e>
```

this is similar to `E > F` which will only match if `F` is a **direct** child of `E` (no other elements in between).

While

```
E ~ F
```

selects an Element `F` which is preceded by an element `E`. In this case, you have a non-nested structure and `E` and `F` are *Siblings*.

```
<!-- E ~ F will match: -->
<e></e>
<f></f>
```

which again is similar to `E + F` except that here, `F` must follow `E` directly (with no other Element in between).

Comment: @Bolt I used the terminology `child/parent` on purpose because although it is not correct in the strict technical way it sounds more intuitive to many user.

Answer (score 3):

In the latter the two elements "E" and "F" must be *siblings*, not parent / descendent.

This will match `E F`:

```
<e> ... <f> </f> ... </e>
```

and this will match `E ~ F`

```
<e> </e> ... <f> </f>
```

In both cases it's the element "F" which is selected - the element "E" only serves to constrain *which* element "F".

Answer (score 2):

It’s the family tree metaphor (with “child”, “parent”, “descendant” etc.) that causes confusion here. So let’s look at the issue without it:

An element may have sub-elements, e.g. the list items (`li`) inside a list (`ul` or `ol`) are sub-elements of it. The selector `E F` matches an element that matches `F` and is a sub-element of `E`. The selector `E ~  F` is very different: it matches an element that matches `F` if it is a sub-element of element *X* so that *X* also has a sub-element that matches `E` and precedes the one matching `F`. Considering simple type selectors, this means something like

```
<X>...<E>...</E>...<F>this matches E ~ F</F>...</X>
```

In terms of a document tree, visualized as usual with the root at the top, this means that `E F` matches an `F` directly below `E` in the structure, whereas `E ~ F` matches an `F` that is in the same branch at the same level as an `E` and appears before it.

Answer (score 1):

The former selects all F that are descendants of E. The latter selects all F that are siblings of E and occur at any point after it.

The distinction is that in the first case F must be somewhere *inside* E, whereas in the second case F must be an immediate child of the *parent* of E.

In fact, if the F element is *inside* the E element, it is impossible for it to be an immediate child of E's parent. This means that not only are the two selectors different, **they are mutually exclusive**.

An example of `E F`:

```
<e> <f> <f> </e>
    _______
```

An example of `E ~ F`:

```
<e> </e> <g> </g> <f> </f>
                  ________
```

Comment: "they are mutually exclusive" Unless you run into an edge case of having *two* `E` elements, with the structure `<e><e></e><f></f></e>` But that's an edge case; unless your page has a bad case of divitis, you're probably not going to run into a case where `E F` and `E ~ F` will match the same element. They *are* mutually exclusive when talking about the same `E` element of course :)

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I meant for the same E F pair.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question:

```
<p>
    <span id="1"></span>
</p>
<span id="2"></span>
```

```
p span{
    /* this matches the span with id=1 */
}
p ~ span{
    /* this matches the span with id=2 */
}
```

So, in the fist case (`p span`), the `p` is the parent of the span.
In the second case (`p ~ span`), the `p` is a sibling of the span.

Comment: That's not in the question.

Comment: @BoltClock: `descendant` versus `preceded`. I'd say it is, but it might be tricky to understand.